# Interpolating Data from Multiple Parameter SQL Query

Tags: python, database, sqlite, interpolation, pyodbc

I have a database of settings for a machine that has the following parameters:

Outer Diameter (OD) | Inner Diameter (ID) | Power | Speed | Dwell

When using a new material size I want to interpolate the settings from the closest values in order to minimize the adjusting I need to do for new material.

Given a OD and ID that doesn't exist in the database what is the best way to query the database for the closest value > and < the OD and ID combination and from those values interpolate the settings for the new size.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? a code to start?

Comment: "Best" is subjective.

Comment: As hinted in the answer from @Jared, you probably should talk to someone knowledgeable about the machine in question to find out what function to use for your calculation of "closeness". It could be that the OD is far more important than the ID, or vice versa, depending on the operation that the machine is performing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can calculate the "distance" between each row and the desired values, you can order your result set by that, and limit the result set to 1 if you just want the "closest" result:

```
SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY my_distance_calculation(od, id, :given_od, :given_id) LIMIT 1;
```

`my_distance_calculation` doesn't have to be a function.  It can any valid expression in your database's dialect.  For example, this just uses the sum of the absolute difference of each parameter from its given value:

```
SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY ABS(od - :given_od) + ABS(id - :given_id) LIMIT 1;
```

SQLite doesn't have a built-in power function but if it did then you could calculate Euclidean distance:

```
SELECT * FROM settings ORDER BY POW(POW(od - :given_id, 2) + POW(id - :given_id, 2), 0.5) LIMIT 1;
```